# In node.js with express, is there a way of changing the url of a link on the fly?

Tags: node.js, express, redirect, href

I have a link on a page:

`<a href="/application-reference" class="govuk-back-link">Back</a>`

which of course takes the user to '/application-reference'. However, if the session has timed out, I want the user to taken to '/session-ended' instead. Session timed out is detected by the absence of request.session.

I've tried changing the href to send the user back to the same page (i.e. the link is in 'security-code' and takes the user to 'security-code') with the idea that the handling code can look for request.session and decide which page to redirect to, only I can find no way for the code to detect that the page has been called by itself via the back button.

I think the answer is to put something in my express module so that the router.get call that redirects to '/application-reference' will under the right circumstances redirect to '/session-ended'. But I have no idea how to go about this.

I suppose the ideal would be for the '/session-ended' screen to be invoked any time the user clicks on any screen once the session has timed out.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you use any npm package for handing user session? (e.g.: http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cookie-session.html)

Comment: Yes. I use express.

Comment: Do you use `cookie-session` package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your `/application-reference`-handler you could check if the `session` on the `req`-object is still valid. If not `redirect` the request to `/session-ended`:

```
app.get('/application-reference', (req, res) => {
 if(!req.session) { // or a more detailed check for the session's validity
    return res.redirect("/session-ended");
 }
 // rest of the handler-code ...
});
```

An better way to do this is to define a separate `middleware` to check the user's session - this allows you to reuse this middleware and not having to duplicate the check in your handlers:

```
function validateSession(req,res,next) {
 if(!req.session) { // or a more detailed check for the session's validity
   return res.redirect("/session-ended");
 }
 // all is good, go to the next middleware
 next();
});

app.get('/application-reference', validateSession, (req, res) => { ... });
```